# What is the best way to implement images captions?

Tags: html, css

I want to implent images with captions that can go inside content, could be left, right and center aligned.

Parent div has dynamic width, image has dynamic.

How to implement that?

I have tried next thing:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="image" style="display:table;">
    <img src="foo.jpg" alt="" />
    <div style="display:table-caption;caption-side:bottom;">This is the caption.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But at first it doesn't work in FF for images that has width more than parent div.col-lg-4
So with this approach, images should has fixed width, or parent block with display:table. So there is no sense in using that table and table-caption properties. Because you can set width and doesn't use them.

Comment: Asking for “best way” (without even specifying criteria) is primarily opinion-based, especially since there are so many possible approaches here.

Comment: Suppose this question's title can be reworded as "Dynamically sized images with captions" or something of that sort

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way is using `figure` and `figcaption`

http://jsfiddle.net/3n1gm4/rfsYy/

```
<figure>
    <img src="animageURL.jpg" alt="an image" />

    <figcaption>The images caption woo woo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

`figure` is a block level element so you need to set it to `display: table` and `width: 1%` (could be 1px also) to cause it to stretch but be rigid at the same time

```
figure {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Imaging you have 30 such an images, these images shouldn't have width, as well as their parent block, because we have responsive layout. How you could implement this. In my question i mentioned, that parent block and image should have dynamic width.

Comment: For dynamic images sizes i would use "`display: inline-block` for dynamic sizes" (like in the fiddle) the example I gave here in code was for the fixed sized images.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will try fiddler's link tomorrow. I think display:inline-block on parent element wdouldn't work with long caption, if you meant display:inline-block for image, heh... will try, but it seems then caption will in wrong place.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8E2T7/3/ Here is what oyu will get if you will have a longer caption with parent display:inline-block, so this is the problem. If we would't set parent block width, we can't use long strings in captions. If we use display:table + display:table-caption, we can't make image fit in parent block, if it has bigger initial width.

Comment: I've updated my answer and fiddle to your constraints

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the figure/figcaption is ideal in this situation.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xpUuV/2/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>Text 1</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>Text 2</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>Text 3</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>
```

For responsiveness, set the figures to `inline-block`.

```
.wrapper { /* just an example */
    width:90%;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

figure {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

figure img {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it tomorrow, and will reply.

Comment: Here is your example with longer captions http://jsfiddle.net/KMctL/1/

Comment: Here's a quick update with the images centered. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/KMctL/2/ Obviously, if you want to limit any width, you have to apply it manually.

Comment: If you will try my code snippet from questions description, you will mention that caption content, wouldn't exceed parent block whether width was setted for it or not. 

So the questions is how to combine that one solution with another, that wouldn't allow image to exceed parent width.